# LDAP web application using Single sign-on authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, openid, single-sign-on

I am developing a LDAP web application to access windows active directory contents. I am new to LDAP and single sign-on authentication. At first step, I have developed log in service using "unboundid" java sdk, but now I want to change it to work with single sign-on or open-id authentication. Could any one suggest me solutions/resources for how to perform user authentication of LDAP web application using single sign-on mechanism?

I have gone through some posts out there on internet, but all they are related to open-id authentication using  LDAP server. No one has mentioned how to do it for LDAP web application. Thanks in advance for your suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

`LDAP` (or any auth abomination formed with it) won't provide you with true `SSO` (Single Sign On), you will need to implement it using the `WWW-Authenticate` header and negotiating for kerberos.

This is one idea that will work with an existing `AD` Server.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication?rq=1) is an excellent question regarding authentication

Comment: Thanks. I will check that option.